# Sunlight damage to electrical supply cable

Tags: electrical

This is an image of the electrical supply cable that runs from the meter into my house. It is about 3 years old. I am just learning the importance of protecting electrical cable insulation from UV rays. I plan to have this covered with liquid tight. However, I noticed that the cable has already been affected by the light (see the image). Is this level of damage warrant replacement, or if I cover it correctly using liquid right, would the damage stop from getting worse?

[image]

Comment: Please show the cable type codes printed on the cable.

Comment: Can ou show where the cable goes?

Answer (score 2):

Barring a completely incompetent and uninspected installation, the cable type used for service entrance is UV resistant and safe for exposure to sunlight. You may have a bit of dirt or mold/mildew on your cable that you are misinterpreting as sunlight damage.

One manufacturer page (as an example only) states (the sunlight resistance is part of the cable type specification, not specific to any one manufacturer):

> Jacket and Inner Conductors are Sunlight Resistant.

*Quote source: https://assets.southwire.com/ImConvServlet/imconv/7f1133975e3e4b8c5ab3ee2f1881b50f3d3d4ef8/origin?assetDescr=Aluminum%20Service%20Entrance%20SEU%20Cable.spec*